# Virtual box installation of Debian 3.0 (Woody) can't find harddrive

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I'm trying to install an old Debian 3.0 in Virtual Box in order to emulate a system but I get an error message that it can't find the hard drive. What could be the matter?
[image]

Comment: Did you provide one? The virtual box machine setting page would be helpful.

Comment: What is the HDD controller set to in VirtualBox? Try IDE, which should be supported by such an old distribution.

Comment: @Thomas That solved everything. I accept that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it was a misconfigured HDD controller. As older Linux kernels/distributions lack of support of modern HDD controllers, one has to use IDE which should be supported on old kernels/distributions.